# A list of trusted Bitcoin websites?

Tags: websites, trust

Is there some trusted website that maintains a list of Bitcoin-related websites and their reputation? For example, if I wanted to check if betsofbitco.in is a legitimate websites (it pays rewards fairly, etc.), where should I turn, asides digging through the forum?

Comment: If the answer has only several votes, it is not trustworthy answer :-)

Comment: I came across a [Google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pFHJ34pZ_5Umfmlk_eAIcBSscSAA-3xd6qWYzeEYhec/edit) which has a list of bitcoin websites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TheBitcoinReview](http://www.thebitcoinreview.com/)

This site has what you are looking for, but it is a new site and doesn't have a ton of reviews. You can help the website by posting a review for a Bitcoin business you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

there is no list of bitcoin trusted websites, but you can check some things  to have a good idea of the trust you can give to a website :

- check the whois :

  - anonymous whois ( domainsbyproxy or other ) : -1
  - recent website ( created 1 or 2 months ago ) : -1
  - old and known website : +1
- check the bitcoinpolice website ( bitcoin.crimeunit.net/wiki/index.php ) there could be a report here ( bitcoin.crimeunit.net/wiki/index.php/MyBitcoin as an example )
- if you can use IRC, come ask on #bitcoin-otc and #bitcoin-police IRC channels on freenode IRC server
- bitcoin-otc is a p2p bitcoin exchange, building a reputation system ( wiki.bitcoin-otc.com/wiki/OTC_Rating_System ) , if a website is operated by an old and trusted otc member ( example of old trusted user :  bitcoin-otc.com/viewratingdetail.php?nick=ne0futur ) you can probably trust the website.
- help us making it better, report any problem to the bitcoin-police

Answer (score 2):

Bets of Bitcoin admin here. I think the best way is still digging the forums. But usually bitcointalk.org has one large thread per website where people address their complaints and admins reply, so it is not that hard. For example ours is here:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=37069.0

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions about our service.

Comment: +1 for the forum suggestion.  Still by far the biggest community of bitcoin users and therefore likely the most comprehensive place to find reputation comments on sites.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the first go-to-site is the [wiki page on bitcoin.it](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade), which is linked from the bitcoin.org front page. Of course, it does not guarantee for anyone (they have the following disclaimer: "it still remains up to you to decide whether you trust the service provider or not"), but I would hope that really fishy sites do not make it on the list (or at least do not stay there very long).

Answer (score 1):

I started the [Bitcoin Better Business Bureau](http://www.thebitcointrader.com/p/bitcoin-better-business-bureau.html) (BBBB) to maintain a list of sites of good reputation within the community.  Users can also leave complaints about sites so that others can see if they have a history of indiscretion.

Answer (score 1):

List of bitcoin websites on http://stuffexists.com/
If you find any "untrusted" sites on there, there email is at the bottom and you can let them know.

Comment: Website a parked domain